# Handling cannot insert Null into in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have an `insert` statement where in i am inserting the data from `table_abc` to `table_job`. Now there is mandatory column in effec_start_date in table_job,
but this effec_start_date is not mandatory in table_Abc. Hence there may be null values too in effec_start_date of table_abc.
While inserting from `table_abc` to `table_job` it is going into exception 
stating

```
-1400 - ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("HR"."table_job"."EFF_START_DATE")
```

and obviously when querying table_job it is not returning any value

Is there a possibility to insert the not null values for effective_Start_date in table_job and for only null values it goes into exception

```
insert into table_job
(job_code,
eff_start_date,
eff_end_date,
config_id
)

select * from table_Abc;
```

Comment: Do you want to use a default value when the ABC value is null; or exclude those rows from the insert; or log the errors you get? Not clear if you actually want/need the errors.

Comment: @AlexPoole- No exclude those rows only from the insert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to filter your data in the select statement

```
insert into table_job
(job_code,
eff_start_date,
eff_end_date,
config_id
)
select * from table_Abc
where eff_start_date is not null;
```